# Shebang's relation to current shell

Tags: shell, tcsh, shebang

If my current shell is a tcsh shell (confirmed with `>echo $shell` and `>ps $$` etc.), do I have to write shebangs like `#! bin/tcsh` and have only that kind of scripts to run properly?

I made scripts with sh shebangs `#! bin/sh` and they run properly, although my shell was always a *tcsh* shell. My scripts had forloops, which are different in *sh* and *tcsh*.

Do I need to change my current *tcsh* shell into *sh* shell in order to run scripts with sh shebangs?
Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your sh is redirected to tcsh. Check with `ls -l /bin/sh`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to linux and I'm not sure I understood your answer. ls is for listing the contents, right?I tried it out and I got "No such file or directory" .Oops! Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF your shebang lines were actually `#! bin/sh` then the reason that they worked correctly is because that path doesn't exist and your current shell is taking over running of the script.

Fix the path in the shebang line to be a valid absolute path `#!/bin/sh` and I expect you will see the scripts start to fail.

See http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ for more about the shebang line that you likely care about.

Comment: So you're telling that with a current tcsh shell, i need to have scripts starting with tcsh shebangs. Right? So, the shebang must be the 'same' with my current shell. Can you please confirm this?

Comment: @eva_thess No. That's not what I said (or meant). What I said was that when you have an incorrect shebang line (like `#! bin/sh` which is a relative path at best) the shebang mechanism will fail and the current shell might decide to take over and run the script itself. Fix the path in your shebang line and it should start working and that shell should run.